# Error TS2339: Property 'Default' does not exist on type 'string'.**

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, typescript

I am new to Angular 2
- My functionality is working fine in fiddle but when I put in the code base I am getting below errors.

**app/components/playing-cables/-update.ts(82,12): error TS2339: Property 'options' does not exist on type 'jQuery'.
app/components/playing-cables/-update.ts(99,21): error TS2339: Property 'Default' does not exist on type 'string'.**

```
    storedPreferences.Default = {
    dropdown.options = function(data, selectedKey) {
```

- Can you tell me how to fix it.
- Providing my code below.
- Working code http://jsfiddle.net/yk0up9ht/

```or-tag-here
import {Component, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { sportService } from '../../services/sport.service';
import {playesRightBarMultiTabComponent} from '../playing-sports/playes-right-bar-multi-tab'
import {playerComponent} from '../player/player.component';
import {ProgressCircle} from '../shared/progress/progress-circle';
import {playeService} from '../../services/playeService';
import {playingsportsEvergreen} from '../playing-sports/playe-sports-evergreen';
import {TextDecoder} from 'text-encoding-shim';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import {NetworkCarousel} from '../shared/content/network-carousel';
import {KendoGridComponent} from '../grid/grid.component';
import { TranslateService } from '../../translate/translate.service';
//import { ProgressCircle } from '../shared/progress/progress-circle';



@Component({
    selector: 'downlinkBulkUpdate',
    templateUrl: "./app/components/playing-cables/downlink-bulk-update.html",
})

export class downlinkBulkUpdate {
    public dataSourceVal;
    public selectedRowsUID = [];
    private count: boolean = true;
    private selectAll: boolean;


    @ViewChild(KendoGridComponent) private gridkendo: KendoGridComponent;

    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef,private router: Router){
    }

    private kendocommand = {
        edit: { createAt: "bottom" },
        group: false,
        reorder: true,
        resize: true,
        sort: true,
        filter: { mode: "row,menu" },
        autoBind: false,
        pager: { messages: { display: "Showing {0} to {1} of {2} entries" } },
        model: {},
        columns: [],
        pagesize: 50,
        getComponentUrl: "admin/v1/lockedItems",
        saveStatus: false,
        excelfileUidName: "ViewUnlockExport",
        excelFileName: {
            fileName: "ViewUnlockExport",
            allPages: true
        },
        change: function (e) {
            console.log("kendocommand downlink-bulk-update");

            $('tr').find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
            $('tr.k-state-selected').find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
        },
        searchFields: []
    };

    ngOnInit() {

        $("tr th[data-field='codeLong']").hide();



        if ($('input.checkbox_check').prop('checked')) {
          //blah blah
          alert("checked");

          $("tr th[data-field='codeLong']").show();
        }


        $("#win1").hide();

        /*document.getElementById('cars').options[0].text = localStorage.getItem("someVarName") || 'unkonwn';
        var dropdown = $('<select>');
        alert("I am here dropdownmenu select"); */
            var dropdown = $('#cars');
        dropdown.options = function(data, selectedKey) {
          var self = this;
          var newOptions = '<option value="Default">Default</option>'; //create one objec to save new options
          $.each(data, function(ix, val) {
           var selected = (val == selectedKey) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
              if (val != 'Default') {
                newOptions += '<option value="' + val + '" ' + selected + '>' + val + '</option>';
             }
            //data.push(option);
          });
          self.html(newOptions);
          self.change();
        }
        //var array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
        var array = [];
        var storedPreferences = localStorage.getItem('preferences');
        storedPreferences = (storedPreferences) ? JSON.parse(storedPreferences) : {};
        storedPreferences.Default = {
            columns: [0,1,2],
        };
        for (var storedPreference in storedPreferences) {
            array.push(storedPreference);
        }
        dropdown.options(array, 'Default');
        //$('body').append(dropdown);
        $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(ix, val) {
          //should clear out the current options
          //and replace with the new array
          alert("I am here dropdownmenu");
          var newArray = ['four', 'five', 'six'];
          dropdown.options(newArray, 'Default');
        });



        $("#open1").click(function() {
          alert("I am here");

          $("#win1").show().kendoWindow({
            width: "300px",
            height: "500px",
            modal: true,
            title: "Window 1"
          });
          $("#win1").data("kendoWindow").open();
        });

        $("#clearPrefrence").click(function() {
          alert("clearPrefrence");
          //localStorage.clear();
          //$("#cars option[value=volvo]").remove();
          if ($('#cars').val() != 'Default') {
            var preferences = localStorage.getItem('preferences');
            if (preferences) {
                preferences = JSON.parse(preferences);
            }
            else {
                preferences = {};
            }
              delete preferences[$('#cars').val()];
              localStorage.setItem('preferences', JSON.stringify(preferences));
              $("#cars option:selected").remove();
            $("#cars").change();
          }

        });

        $("#win1Submit").click(function() {

          var testingMickey = $("#mickey").val();
          alert("win1Submit I am here--->" + testingMickey);
          //document.getElementById('cars').options[0].text = testingMickey;

          var someVarName = testingMickey;
          var preferences = localStorage.getItem('preferences');
          if (preferences) {
              preferences = JSON.parse(preferences);
          }
          else {
              preferences = {};
          }
          var preference = {
            columns: [],
          }
          $('#rmenu input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
              preference.columns.push($(this).data('index'));
          });
          preferences[testingMickey] = preference;
          localStorage.setItem('preferences', JSON.stringify(preferences));
          var getItemsomeVarName1 = localStorage.getItem('preferences');
          getItemsomeVarName1 = JSON.parse(getItemsomeVarName1);
          var optionArray = [];
          for (var key in getItemsomeVarName1) {
              optionArray.push(key);
          }
          alert("getItemsomeVarName1 I am here--->" + getItemsomeVarName1[testingMickey].columns.length);
                dropdown.options(optionArray, testingMickey);
          $("#win1").data("kendoWindow").close();

        });




        setGrid();

         function toggleColumns() {
            $('#rmenu input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index) {
              $(this).data('index', index);
            $(this).attr('data-index', index); 
          });
          $('#rmenu input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
            var index = $(this).data('index') + 1;
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.k-grid-header-wrap > table tr th:nth-child(' + index + '),table.k-focusable tr td:nth-child(' + index + ')').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.k-grid-header-wrap > table tr th:nth-child(' + index + '),table.k-focusable tr td:nth-child(' + index + ')').hide();
            }
          });

          $('select').change(function() {
              $('#rmenu input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked').prop('checked', false);
              var preferences = localStorage.getItem('preferences');
            preferences = (preferences) ? JSON.parse(preferences) : {};
            var columns = [0,1,2];
            var key = $(this).val();
            if (preferences && preferences[key]) {
                columns = preferences[key].columns;
            }
            for (var a = 0; a < columns.length; a++) {
                $('#rmenu input[type=checkbox][data-index=' + a + ']').prop('checked', true).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }

            $('#rmenu input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
                $(this).change();
            });
          });
        }

        toggleColumns();

        $('.k-grid-header').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let menu = document.getElementById("rmenu");
          menu.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
          menu.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';

          menu.className = "show";
        });

        $(document).bind("click", function(event) {
          document.getElementById("rmenu").className = "hide";
        });



        function setGrid() {

          var ds1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
              read: {
                //using jsfiddle echo service to simulate JSON endpoint
                url: "/echo/json/",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                  // /echo/json/ echoes the JSON which you pass as an argument
                  json: JSON.stringify({
                    "country": [{
                        "codeLong": "AUT",
                        "codeShort": "AT",
                        "name": "Austria"
                      },
                      {
                        "codeLong": "BEL",
                        "codeShort": "BE",
                        "name": "Belgium"
                      },
                      {
                        "codeLong": "BGR",
                        "codeShort": "BG",
                        "name": "Bulgaria"
                      }
                    ]
                  })
                }
              }
            },
            schema: {
              data: "country",
              model: {
                fields: {
                  codeLong: {
                    type: "string"
                  },
                  codeShort: {
                    type: "string"
                  },
                  name: {
                    type: "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          });



          $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: ds1,
            height: 180,
            scrollable: {
              virtual: true
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "codeLong",
                title: "codeLong"
              },
              {
                field: "codeShort",
                title: "codeShort"
              },
              {
                field: "name",
                title: "name"
              }

            ]
          });
        }






        alert("downlink-bulk-update");
        console.log("downlink-bulk-update");
        let that = this;

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".showHideIcon").click(function(){
                alert("titleSearchResults");
            });
        });

        this.kendocommand.model = {
            id: "isSelected",
            fields: {
                contextRow: { editable: false },
                isSelected: { type: "boolean", editable: true, filterable: false },
                moduleName: { type: "string", editable: false },
                entityId: { type: "string", filterable: true, editable: false, nullable: false },
                entityName: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                network: { type: "string", editable: false },
                entityType: { type: "string", editable: false },
                userLocked: { type: "string", editable: false },
                additionalComments: { type: "string", editable: false },
                checkOutDate: { editable: false }

            }
        };
        this.kendocommand.columns = [
            {
                field: 'contextRow',
                width: 25, locked: true
            },
            {
                field: "isSelected", filterable: false, sortable: false, editable: true, title: "Is Selected",
                template: function (container) { return that.checkboxchecker(container, "isSelected") },
                width: 30,
                headerTemplate: '<span class="displayBlock"><input type="checkbox" id="unlockCheck" /></span>'
            },
            {
                field: "moduleName",
                title: "Module Name", filterable: that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains", "moduleName"), headerAttributes: { class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled" },
                template: function moduleName(options) {
                    console.log("downlink-bulk-update 2");
                    return that.gridTemplate(options, "moduleName", false);
                },
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "entityId", title: "ID",
                filterable: that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("eq", "entityId"),
                headerAttributes: { class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled" },
                template: function entityId(options) {
                    console.log("ending this.kendocommand.columns");

                    return that.gridTemplate(options, "entityId", false);
                },

                width: 90
            }, {
                field: "entityName", filterable: that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains", "entityName"), headerAttributes: { class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled" },
                template: function entityName(options) {
                    return that.gridTemplate(options, "entityName", false);
                },
                title: "Name",
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "network",
                title: "Network",
                filterable: that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains", "network"), headerAttributes: { class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled" },
                template: function networkName(options) {
                    return that.gridTemplate(options, "network", false);
                },

                width: 110
            }, {
                field: "entityType",
                title: "Type", filterable: that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains", "entityType"), headerAttributes: { class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled" },
                template: function entityType(options) {
                    return that.gridTemplate(options, "entityType", false);
                },
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "userLocked",
                title: "User Locked", filterable: that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains", "userLocked"), headerAttributes: { class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled" },
                template: function userLocked(options) {
                    return that.gridTemplate(options, "userLocked", false);
                },
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "additionalComments",
                title: "Additional Comments bulk", filterable: that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains", "additionalComments"), headerAttributes: { class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled" },
                template: function additionalComments(options) {
                    return that.gridTemplate(options, "additionalComments", false);
                },
                width: 200
            }, {
                field: "checkOutDate",
                title: "Date Checked Out", filterable: that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains", "checkOutDate"), headerAttributes: { class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled" },
                template: function checkOutDate(options) {
                    return that.gridTemplate(options, "checkOutDate", false);
                },
                width: 200
            }
        ];

        console.log("ending this.kendocommand.columns");
    }

    private gridTemplate(options: any, fieldName: any, mandatory: any) {
        console.log("gridTemplate downlink-bulk-update");

        let value = options[fieldName];
        if (options[fieldName] == null || options[fieldName] == undefined) {
            value = "";
            options[fieldName] = " ";
        }
        options[fieldName + "FilterRowId"] = value;
        return value;
    }

    checkboxchecker(container, fieldName: any): any {
        console.log("checkboxchecker downlink-bulk-update");

        if ((this.selectedRowsUID.indexOf(container.uid) != -1) || this.selectAll) {
            container.isSelected = true;
            return '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="display:block;" class="textAligncenter unlockCheckbox" #= fieldName ? \'checked="checked"\' : "false" #= fieldName/>';

        } else {
            this.count = true;
            container.isSelected = false;
            return '<input type="checkbox" style="display:block;" class="textAligncenter unlockCheckbox" #= fieldName ? \'checked="checked"\' : "false" #= fieldName/>';
        }
    }

}



‌
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the 'options' problems occurs here:

```
var dropdown = $('#cars');
dropdown.options = function(data, selectedKey) ...
```

Well, this works in JavaScript, but the error the TypeScript compiler gives you is due to static type-checking. `dropdown` is here a jQuery object, and that type (assuming you're using type definitions for jQuery) does not declare a `options` property, so assigning to it generates an error. To allow TypeScript to do this, you must typecast to `any`, so the object behaves like any JavaScript object:

```
var dropdown: any = $('#cars');
dropdown.options = (...)
```

In the case of `.Default` it is the same error: you are declaring `storedPreferences` as

```
var storedPreferences = localStorage.getItem(...);
```

TypeScript knows that `localStorage.getItem` returns a `string`, so it considers `storedPreferences` to be of type string. In TypeScript you cannot change the type of a variable. In fact, it's the kind of thing it has been designed to prevent (as it is common in JavaScript and cause of frequent errors). TypeScript knows that `string` does not have a `Default` property and indicates an error.

To avoid this, again, you must declare `storedPreferences` to be of type `any`:

```
let storedPreferences: any = localStorage.getItem(...);
```

The problem is that you're programming in TypeScript as if it were JavaScript, and that's why you're getting compiler errors. In TypeScript you cannot add new properties to an object of a known type. To do this, you must previously declare the object as `any`, so TypeScript behaves exactly like JavaScript (though this way you lose TypeScript advantages).

Besides all this, you should avoid using `var` and use `let` or `const` instead.

The code in jsfiddle works, because that is JavaScript code, not TypeScript code.